# Moved site to new IIS (7.5) PHP (5.4.21) server (same SQL backend)

Tags: php, iis-7, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm in the process of moving a site from one 2008 R2 server to another 2008 R.
(EDIT:  both are fully updated)
The 'new' server did not have PHP installed so I installed PHP, then copied all the PHP files from the original server so should be identical.  The site is backed by a SQL server which for all intents is identical (scripted the original and ran the script on the new). I also copied the original PHP documents.

It all works fine, except for a supposed issue with $_SESSIONS?  Login works fine but when navigating between pages, the login page is revisted - every time.  This does not happen when using the same files on the original server.

Anyone have any ideas and/or can point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your kind consideration!

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP.ini file for the location where Sessions are being saved.  You will then need to check the Security permissions on that folder and make sure the Account running your website has access to write and delete files here.

If a Session folder was not specified I believe the default location in the Temp folder.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Chambrln. The session variables are being written to the temp folder and the correct information is being recorded but it appears that the information is not available to the application itself? makes no sense to me?!